# if conditional inside string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework

I need to set innerhtml of an element, but some part of the code is conditional. Since I cannot append to innerHtml I want to put a conditional. I am quite new to JS, so i couldnt find a way of doing this because I am messing up with the signs " ` '.

I saw some methos to append to innerHtml but I want a cleaner way to do this

```
    el.innerHTML = `
    <ion-avatar slot="start">
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/${i + originalLength}?d=monsterid&f=y">
      </ion-avatar>

    <ion-label>
    <name>${users[t].name}</name>
    <br>

        ******IF JS CONDITIONAL( IF ${users[t].lista} !="") ******    
    <ion-chip><ion-label><lista><p>Lista ${users[t].lista}</p></lista></ion-label></ion-chip>
        <br>
        ******END IF JS CONDITIONAL******

        <ion-chip outline color="primary"><ion-icon name="cash"></ion-icon><p><?php echo $product->getLabelPrice1() ?>: ${users[t].valor1} <?php echo $product->getLabelPrice2() ?>: ${users[t].valor2}</p></ion-chip>

    </ion-label>
    `;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `conditional (ternary) operator` Like:

```
${
    foo === 1 ?                                       //Check if variable is one            
        '============= foo is 1 ============='        //If condition above is true              
    :           
        '============= foo NOT is 1 ============='    //If condition above is false
}
```

Example

```js
let foo = 1;

let str = `
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    
     ${
        foo === 1 ? 
     
           '============= foo is 1 ============='
     
        :
     
           '============= foo NOT is 1 ============='
     }
    
 Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
 Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
 `;

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Happy to help :)